# JSON output for highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

So I have finally managed to get a chart generated, but the problem is that for some reason the data from JSON is not displayed - ie I get a blank chart.

In the chart options I simply have:

```
series : [{
    name: '2000',
    data: [],
}]
```

The AJAX call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'data.php',
    datatype : 'json',
    success : function (json) {
        options.series[0].data = json['data'];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    },
});
}
```

And the data.php output looks like this:

```
{"data":[-1.4,-1.4,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.2,-1.3,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2]}
```

Im becoming desperate as I tried everything and still get just a blank chart with no data.

Comment: are any errors showing up in your javascript console?  What is your ajax call returning, is it resulting in `200` with the expected response from your php?

Comment: no there are no errors, I am just not sure wheather it is ok, if the final line of data.php is:

echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

and before that I have 
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($x)){
    $rows['data'][] = $r['Temp'];
}

Which loads the data, the actual "echo" produces:
{"data":[-1.4,-1.4,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.2,-1.3,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2]}

Comment: why dont you just hardcode some of the data to series.data and see if you are getting a chart with some data

Comment: also try printing json, before you call options.series[0].data = json['data']

Comment: I tried to delete the options.series..... line and instead I put some data into the data in the series and then I get a normal chart with the data points.

Comment: hmm this is weired, so I tried to alert "json" and it alerts what I have written above, if I try to alert json['data'] I get "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Internet Explorer, those extra commas will cause you problems.

```
series : [{
    name: '2000',
    data: []
}]

$.ajax({
    url : 'data.php',
    datatype : 'json',
    success : function (json) {
        options.series[0].data = json['data'];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that your json values are coming back as strings but highcharts is expecting numbers.

In your data.php try typing your variables before json_encoding them:

```
array_push($myArray, (float)$value);
return json_encode(myArray);
```

If your highcharts data looks like:

```
["-1.4","-1.4","-1.3","-1.3","-1.3","-1.3","-1.3","-1.2","-1.3","-1.2","-1.2","-1.2"]
```

It wont render, it needs to be straight number:

```
[-1.4,-1.4,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.2,-1.3,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2]
```